# What is true rps in locust

Tags: python, performance, fastapi, load-testing, locust

I'm curious how many actual requests per second my service is getting while locust load test.

If it has 50 users and shows 6 RPS, does it mean I'm getting 50*6=300 requests per second?

Comment: Yes, It's concurrent request per seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's total number of RPS which Locust is able to achieve.

If you look at [Getting Started page of Locust documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#locust-s-web-interface):

There is "Number of Users"

[image]

and "Total Requests per Second"

[image]

as you can see RPS stopped growing around 40th second of the test and remains the same and users are being added for another minute. Ideally RPS should increase as the load increases, Locust documentation shows classic [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck)

So unless you artificially slowing down Locust using [`wait()` function](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.User.wait) and not capable of getting more than 6 RPS with 50 users - most probably your server needs some optimization.

Also double check your [Locustfile](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html), maybe your load profile differs from your expectations and you don't have 50 concurrent users at the single moment.

More information:

- [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second)
- [What Is Locust Load Testing?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-load-testing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are monitoring from locust UI 6 rps means 6 requests per second regardless of user count. Web UI shows the total rps generated from all workers.